# How To Create A New bash_profile And Connect New Database To It In Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

OS -> Linux

DB -> Oracle 11gR2

Normally my .bash_profile file looks like this:

```
TMP=/tmp; export TMP
TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=abcde.localdomain; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_UNQNAME=DB11G; export ORACLE_UNQNAME
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=DB11G; export ORACLE_SID
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH
```

But I need to do that:

```
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/newdb
```

After that I have to create a new database in newdb.

I'm a newbie oracler and I couldn't find any clear solution. Should I create a directory as newdb and set a new .bash_profile file? If it's a clear solution, how can I do it and after that will my dbca and netca operations work fine? Or something else like this?

Thank you.

Comment: `ORACLE_HOME` has nothing to do with the location of a new database; you can create a new database without changing the `ORACLE_HOME` value.

Comment: If all you want to do is create a new Oracle instance, do not change `ORACLE_HOME` or create any directories. Just set `ORACLE_SID` to the name of the new instance & run dbca. Multiple databases (instances) can run from the same `ORACLE_HOME`. This is not the case in newer versions of Oracle, as you can use PDBs instead

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Sir I know it but I have to do. My new directory should be newdb and I have to create my new database in it.

Comment: @mustaccio Sir I know it but I have to do. My new directory should be newdb and I have to create my new database in it.

Comment: Why isn't `oraenv` being used to set up your environment?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for your participation. Could you elaborate why you (think) you need a sub-directory and/or a new `ORACLE_HOME`? Normally you would install multiple instances of Oracle RDBMS using the same `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_BASE` directories with use of individual `ORACLE_SID` settings. If you are unable to elaborate on your issue, then your question might be closed as **unclear what you are asking**. We are reluctant to give bad advice. (see above comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove all that junk from `.bash_profile`. Use `oraenv`. Example:

```
$ grep u01 /etc/oratab
MIN112:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N
MIN121:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1:N

$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? MIN112
The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle
$ env | grep ORA | sort
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
ORACLE_SID=MIN112

$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [MIN112] ? MIN121
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /u01/app/oracle
$ env | grep ORA | sort
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
ORACLE_SID=MIN121
```

Second, forget `/u01/app/oracle/product/newdb`.
Just run `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbca` and create your other database and provide the necesarry path for datafiles. You do not need another `ORACLE_HOME` for another database.

When you have multiple databases, just put them in `/etc/oratab` (dbca will do this automatically in 11.2), and use `oraenv` or just set `ORACLE_SID` in case of the same `ORACLE_HOME` for switching between them.